# Can work done by conservative forces change the mechanical energy of a system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, potential-energy, conservative-field

It is defined that a constant force is conservative. Does this mean that the work of this force won't change the mechanical energy of the system?

Example: a constant force pulls an object from A to B: its work doesn't depend on on the path so the force is conservative but its work is added to the mechanical energy of the system so the Em is not conserved?
Where do I miss something?

---

Here the force is conservative because of being constant and its work doesnt depend on the path (same Work if moved along the dotted lines) but its work change Em ! ?

[image]

Comment: constant force has always the same direction, orientation and value. If it's conservative it should not change the Em ?

Comment: A conservative force has potential...does a constant force have that

Comment: That's the point: I don't understand these two definitions of a conservative force: it is a constant force and derives from Ep. In my example, is the force derives from Ep ?

Comment: It's not necessary that all  constant forces are conservative...what makes a force conservative is that it has potential and it conserves energy

Comment: the force in your example is not constant and the mechanical energy is not changed....a conservative force by definition means it conserves mechanical energy

Comment: A constant force is conservative :  its work doesn t depend on the path. It is easy to show that with the definition of work.

Comment: A constant force doesn't necessarily mean it is conservative force,only when the constant force is conservative then work done will be independent.I don't know where you got that definition

Comment: For eg ,constant frictional force.Even though it is constant,it is not conservative but gravity being a constant force as well as conservative has it's work done independent of the path

Comment: A constant force is necessarily conservative. The proof comes from the definition of work (definition found in physics textbooks):WAB = SF.dl if F is constant (in value and space) then you can put F outside the integral so WAB= FSdl or Sdl = AB so in the case of a constant force the work is W = F.AB it doesn't depend on the path followed  it depends only on the position of A and B  hence the force is conservative.

Comment: A friction force (even constant in value) will change in direction along different path  so it proofs nothing for the question asked here

Comment: your line-"It is defined that a constant force is conservative", works for only the cases where the constant force is constant for every path.Then this indeed conserves energy otherwise it is a far too much of a generalisation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75495/discussion-between-magemaro-and-devernay-stephane).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No, a conservative force can definitely change the mechanical energy of an object. And yes, the net work does not depend on the path that is taken. If however, the force acts along a closed loop, the net work which is done equals zero.
And yes, it is easy to find a potential for a constant force. Example:
$$
\vec{F} = c \cdot (\vec{e}_x + \vec{e}_y + \vec{e}_z)\\
\Phi = -c\cdot (x +y + z) \\
F = -\nabla \Phi
$$
So note that the total energy of the system can change and only if you perform a closed loop, the net work done by the conservative force will be zero.

Comment: "a conservative force can definitely change the mechanical energy of an object". How?

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition, a conservative force:

- is created by a conservative field(gravitational ,electric field, time independent magnetic field).
- is the work done depend on initial and final position of the object.
- is not constant but  a function of its position vector. force is defined as negetive gradient of a scalar function. Curl of force=0.

For a constant force, these conditions are not satisfied. work done depends on displacement of the body, not on initial and final position of the body. It is actually a non conservative force.

According to the law of conservation of energy,

- when force is conservative, mechanical energy is conserved.
- when force is non-conservative, mechanical energy + work done = conserved quantity.

Comment: but the (actual) displacement is the vector difference between the final and initial positions. For constant forces, the work done i simply the dot product of force and displacement( not distance) and is thus independent of the path taken.