# Change in mechanical energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

When one pulls an object from A to B with a constant force (so a conservative force), the mechanical energy of the object is modified by the work of this force so why is there a law saying that the change in mechanical energy equals the work of non-conservative forces only ?

EDIT:
In this situation:

[image: sliding a block]

is the change of mechanical energy only due to work of friction ? the pull is constant and conservative shouldn't I take its work into account ?

Comment: For context: this question is a follow-up of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/397341/109928

Comment: To be more precise I found this law in several textbooks (high school and university) but shouldn't it be " the change in Em equals the work of non-conservative forces ALONG A CLOSED LOOP" ?

Comment: Are you confusing the total energy of the system and the mechanical energy of an object? The total energy is conserved when conservative forces are applied. But the energy of an object in the system can change.

Comment: *"When one pulls an object from A to B with a constant force (so a conservative force)"* This is an incorrect statement. A constant force pushing something over a distance can easily be non-conservative - the pushing force when pushing a box over the floor an for example

Comment: But a constant force is always conservative.

Comment: @DevernayStéphane No. Friction is not conservative (the work it does disappears as heat) but it is constant while the sliding over a surface is taking place.

Comment: I know that friction force is non-conservative but it is not constant over a loop. Because you have to consider the work along a loop to decide whether a force is conservative or not. So a constant force is conservative.

Comment: @DevernayStéphane A force being conservative has nothing to do with it being constant. Conservative means "conserves (mechanical) energy". A constant friction force has a different work over a loop depending on the velocity or the size of the loop; hence it is *not* conservative.

Comment: A constant force has same direction , orientation and value. If you calculate the work of a constant force from A to B you'll find that the work of this constant force doesn't depend on the path followed from A to B: it is the definition of a conservative force. So a constant force is always conservative.

Comment: @Nicolas strictly speaking a friction force cant be constant meaning constant in value and constant within the space. If you say the friction force is constant it s a mistake because it implies that it is constant in space which is not. But it can be constant in value. So a constant force in value and within space is conservative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context the mechanical energy is the sum of the kinetic energy and potential energy of the block.
There is no change in the gravitational potential energy of the block.

If there was no frictional force then the work done by the external force $F$  would equal the change in kinetic energy of the block.

With a frictional force present the work done by the force $F$ minus the work done by the frictional force would equal the change in kinetic energy of the block.
So the change in mechanical energy (kinetic energy in this case) in the case of the block is due to both external forces (force $F$ and frictional force) acting on the block.

**Update** as a result of a comment

Consider a system which just consists of a block of mass $M$ which is allowed to fall under the influence of a gravitational field of strength $g$ and there is no air resistance.
After falling a distance $h$ the external conservative force (gravitational attraction of the Earth on the block) does work $Mgh$ on the block.
That work done by the gravitational field increases the mechanical energy of the block.
You know that to be true because the block's kinetic energy increases and remembering the fact that for a system composed of just a block you cannot define a gravitational potential energy.

If there is air resistance (a non conservative force) then the block will not gain as much kinetic energy.

Now consider the falling block and the Earth as one system with no air resistance present.
This is an example where the mechanical energy of the system (kinetic energy of the block $+$ kinetic energy of the Earth $+$ gravitational potential energy of the Earth & block) stays the same.
You would often write that the loss in gravitational potential energy is equal to the gain in kinetic energy which follows from the mechanical energy of the Earth & block system staying the same.

Introducing air resistance (a non-conservative force) changes things.
You now have a situation where the mechanical energy of the Earth & block system decrease because (negative) work has been done by the air resistance and some of the mechanical energy of the Earth & block system has been converted into heat, sound and possibly light.

So I think your statement *the change in mechanical energy equals the work of non-conservative forces only* is the example of the falling block with air resistance when the system being considered if the block and the Earth.

Comment: Yes that's what I think so I still have my problem: why do i find physics textbooks explaining that the change in mechanical energy is only due to non conservative force ! Here the pull is conservative and contributes to the change of Em.

Comment: @DevernayStéphane I have written an update to my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: Thanks it helped. I realised that because the pull derives from a potential it is the same as the behavior of the weight in a fall concerning potential and kinetic energy.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanical energy is a term that covers kinetic energy $K$ and potential energies $U$ (gravitational $U_g$, elastic $U_{el}$ etc.).

A swinging pendulum is an example. When swinging downwards, gravitational potential energy $U_g$ is converted into kinetic energy $K$. When swinging upwards, the opposite takes place. Those energy forms simply transform into one another and never leave the system.

But doesn't gravity do work in this system? **Yes, it does**. Gravity is a conservative force. The work done by conservative forces is what we call **potential energies**. So gravity's work is **already included** in this consideration.

The reason for this "renaming" is that when a conservative force does work, that work is *stored*. The system can return to its original state again by releasing that energy. In other words, work done by a conservative force **doesn't leave the system**. Only work done by non-conservative forces disappears and leaves the system, causing the total energy to reduce.

Comment: thank you but could you consider my edit there's still something I can't understand

Comment: @DevernayStéphane If a pulling force is conservative, then the work is does in order to increase the kinetic energy, was already stored in the system beforehand as potential energy. If not, then we wouldn't call it a conservative force. (The pulling force could i.e. be a spring contracting, which it can only due because energy was stored in the already stretched spring.) So of course, if you call a force conservative, then it causes no change in the total energy, because its energy contribution is already included - if it wasn't, then we wouldn't have called the force conservative.

Comment: I found a satisfying solution thanks to you and Farcher. The pull derives from a potential energy so the change of Ep equals - W of the pull and so work added to the Em is compensated by the loss of Ep. So the statement: " The change of Em is due to the works of the non conservative forces "is true. It's just that it is unusual to consider the pull as the conservative force with a potential energy. I was used to reason with weight not pull ! Thanks.

Comment: @DevernayStéphane Glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I think of it this way:

**The mechanical energy of that body is equal to the sum of its macroscopic kinetic energy and macroscopic potencial energy.**

**A conservative force is a force which doesn’t alter a body’s mechanical energy, it only converts between its kinetic energy and potencial energy**: suppose a free falling object (only subjected to the force of gravity, and not to air resistance or other forces). It was someplace above the ground with something holding it (something with a force exactly equal in magnitude to the force of gravity and opposite to it, hence why it stays still in place and doesn’t move) but now, in this instant, that something suddenly disappeared, the body’s potencial energy is, let’s say, 10J. As it starts accelerating downwards gains more and more kinetic energy: (PE=10J and KE=0J; PE=7.35J and KE=2.65J; PE=1J and KE=9J and finally, the instant before it hits the floor and before some of that energy is converted, PE=0J and KE is 10J.)

**An applied force is not conservative because of being constant. Constantly or not constantly it alters a body’s mechanical energy.** For instance, the force required to in a previous, previous moment, make that same body rise from its equilibrium state on the ground (at PE=0J and KE=0J) to the start of our experiment “up top” (at PE=10J and KE=0J) is non-conservative. Comparing the initial and final states it gave it potential energy.

**In your problem: the constantly applied force is non-conservative (it is giving it KE at no expense of PE; moves faster, same distance from the center of the earth, or from whichever point you consider as the origin, like the surface), the friction force is non-conservative (it is taking KE from it without giving it PE), the gravitational force is conservative (and also counteracted by the normal force so “it doesn’t do anything”).**

Basically the answer after all my rabble is that it is *because that force is also non-conservative.* There are non-conservative forces that do potent work, add energy to a system, instead of resistant work, taking it out, like friction.

This may help out:
[image]

*[The work done by conservative forces is equal to minus the potential energy difference; as a body freefalls and gravity’s force does positive work, that body’s potential energy decreases by the same amount as the positive work done. If it goes upward, same thing but in reverse: negative work, “added” potential energy. / The work done by non-conservative forces is equal to the change in mechanical energy, “duh” I suppose. / The work done by the resultant of the forces is equal to the change in kinetic energy, as per the Work-Energy Theorem reasoned from Newton’s second law.]*

Rearranging...

[image]

*[It all “fits”.]*

I apologize for any mistake. I’m also learning.